# How to create a floating window in VSCode extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Im trying to make a VSCode extension and is it possible to create a small window on top of the main window?
Like Youtube Mini Player? 

[image: image1]

It should be draggable up and down around the left corner.
Any idea would be helpful!

Comment: I don't think the VSCode API allows something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create something that's similar, by using a WebView instance, which creates an absolutely positioned div within that page. This would not be movable outside of that WebView but at least you can freely position it within that.

But a bit of a warning: keep in mind vscode is mainly a text editor! It shouldn't be misused as a general webbrowser or media tool or something like that.

Comment: Ill try.. Thanks! No Im going to use it as a preview panel :)

Comment: OK, glad to hear that. Don't forget to accept my answer if it was helpful for you.